# How to display count of unique subjects in legend of scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the below code and would like to display the count of unique `Subject` (a variable in the dataset) for each visit if possible on the legend or somewhere on the graph.

```
#All Subjects on one plot
ggplot(data=PKData, aes(x=NewTime, y=Concentration, colour=factor(Sub)))+
  scale_colour_manual(name=" ",values = c("1"="blue", "2"="red"), 
                      labels=c("Cycle1", "Cycle4"))+
  #stat_summary(aes(y = SUBJECT, group = Visit), fun.y=count, colour="red", geom="line")+
  ggtitle("Concentration time plot")+
  geom_line(aes(group=sub1),  size=1) +

  theme(plot.title=element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=10))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, angle = 90, face="bold"))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13, angle = 00, face="bold"))+

  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +

  labs(x="Time", y="Venetoclax Concentration (ng/mL)")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1"="C1D1 Pre", "2"="C1D1 Post", "3"="C4D1 Pre", "4"= "C4D1 Post"))+
ggsave("AllSubjects.pdf",width=12,height=8)

Subject  Visit    Time_Text  Concentration NewTime Sub sub1
11000    Cycle1   PRE           84.6         1       1   1
11000    Cycle1   POST          344          2       1   1
11000    Cycle4   PRE           172          3       2   2
11000    Cycle4   POST          858          4       2   2
11050    Cycle1   PRE           855          2       1   3
11050    Cyce4    POST          168          3       2   4
11050    Cyce4    POST          581          4       2   4
11051    Cycle1   PRE           380          1       1   5
11051    Cycle1   PRE           1500         2       1   5
11051    Cycle4   POST          372          3       2   6
11051    Cycle4   POST          876          4       2   6
11058    Cycle1   PRE           1540         1       1   7
11058    Cycle1   POST          1940         2       1   7
11058    Cycle4   PRE           1520         3       2   8
11058    Cycle4   POST          3290         4       2   8
```

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide a small example dataset so we can reproduce your example?

Comment: Here is an example: